# open -g command still opens application in the foreground

Tags: macos, bash, google-chrome

When I run the command `open -ga /Applications/Google_Chrome.app http://example.com` the application behaves normally and opens the url in Chrome without bringing the application to the foreground.

But if I run the command `open -ga /Applications/Google_Chrome.app` without specifying a url, the application opens in the foreground.

However running `open -ga /Applications/Safari.app` works as expected and does not bring the application to the foreground regardless of whether a url is specified or not.

#### from the `open` man pages

> **`-a application`**
>   *`Specifies the application to use for opening the file`*
>
> **`-g`** *`Do not bring the application to the foreground`*

Why is Chrome still opening in the foreground when the `-g` option is passed? And how can I make it not do that?